# What causes the type check failed for prop error in this Vue 3 application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a small **[Todo App](https://github.com/Ajax30/Vue-3-To-Do)** with Vue 3. In App.vue I have the 3 child components:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header 
    title="My todo list" 
    :unsolvedTodos = []
    />

    <List 
      :todos="todos"
      dataIsLoaded=false 
      @delete-todo="deleteTodo" 
      @toggle-todo="toggleTodo" />

    <Footer
      :isValidInput = true
      newTitle = ""
      placeholder="+ Add new todo"
      validationMsg = "Please add at least 3 characters"
      @add-todo="addTodo"
      />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Header from './components/Header.vue'
import List from './components/List.vue'
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    List,
    Footer
  },
  // More code
}

</script>
```

In the List.vue component I have:

```
<template>
  <ul class="todo-list" v-if=dataIsLoaded>
      <TodoItem v-for="todo in todos.slice().reverse()"
        :key="todo.id" 
        :class="{done: todo.completed}" 
        :todo="todo" 
        @delete-todo="$emit('delete-todo', todo.id)"
        @toggle-todo="$emit('toggle-todo', todo)"
        />
    </ul>
    <div class="loader" v-else></div>   
</template>

<script>
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem.vue";

export default {
  name: 'List',

  components: {
    TodoItem,
  },

  props: {
    dataIsLoaded: Boolean,
    todos: Array
  },

  emits: ['delete-todo', 'toggle-todo']
}
</script>
```

#### The problem

As can be seen above, I have explicitly set `dataIsLoaded` to a boolean.

Yet, in the console, I get the error:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "dataIsLoaded". Expected Boolean, got String with value "false".
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `bind` it to parse the value to a `boolean`:

```js
const list = Vue.component('list', { template: "#list", props: { dataisloaded: Boolean } });

new Vue({ el: "#app", components: { list } });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template id="list">
  <div>{{dataisloaded}}</div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <list :dataisloaded=false />
</div>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to pass the value from the `parent` to the `child` component as  a `data` variable:

```js
const list = Vue.component('list', { template: "#list", props: { dataisloaded: Boolean } });

new Vue({ 
  el: "#app", 
  components: { list },
  data: () => ({
    dataisloaded: false
  }),
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => this.dataisloaded = true, 2000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template id="list">
  <div>{{dataisloaded}}</div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <list :dataisloaded="dataisloaded" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, cook, but now `this.dataIsLoaded` does not change to `true`. :(

Comment: How are you changing it? It seems that you're not passing a dynamic variable as the value

Comment: Doing `this.dataIsLoaded = true` has no effect. Have a look at the *[Github repo](https://github.com/Ajax30/Vue-3-To-Do)*.

Comment: Yes you're changing the value in the parent component, but as a ``prop`` passed to the child component, you're only defining it as ``false`` which are seperate. Instead, you need to pass the value from the parent to be changed dynamically as shown in the above edited demo.

Comment: I want to keep `dataIsLoaded` false until the data is loaded. Until then, `<div class="loader" v-else></div>`, should be rendered. And it is not. :(

Comment: Are you sure that the prop value is being changed at this stage? A little debugging should solve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232744/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-majed-badawi).

Answer (score 1):

Use `:dataIsLoaded="false"` instead of `dataIsLoaded="false"` wich expects a string by default.